# Has anyone managed to compile nmon for freebsd? or alternatives?

Tags: freebsd

Im used to this great tool called nmon.
if you havnt heard of it you should check it out

Anyway im dabbeling with freebsd, and wanted to see if i can get it compiles.
I managed to get the includes working, more or less atleast.
and it compiles.

But it segfaults when i run it.

So has anyone run compiled it under freebsd or anyone have a good alternative?

Comment: madmaze, did you achieve it on any bsd like os ?

Answer (score 4):

Try these:

```
systat -vmstat 1 # BSD summary of system statistics (1 s intervals)
systat -tcp 1 # BSD tcp connections (try also -ip)
systat -netstat 1 # BSD active network connections
systat -ifstat 1 # BSD network traffic through active interfaces
systat -iostat 1 # BSD CPU and and disk throughput
```

Answer (score 3):

This tool won't work on FreeBSD since it relies on Linux's `/proc` filesystem to gather information. FreeBSD's `/proc` filesystem is totally different.

As an alternative, have a look at the built-in `systat` program.

Comment: Apparently, BSD systat does not differentiate read and write disk throughput, like nmon does, but otherwise it works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I ported nmon to FreeBSD and it works fine; the sources and binaries is here: http://mygnuos.tk/software/free/nmon/

Please note this tool could work on FreeBSD only if you mount the linprocfs at /proc

> mount -t linprocfs procfs /proc